# Как пофиксить ошибку Unable to resolve service?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Добавил в проект asp.net `UserManager`.  При регистрации выходит ошибка. Если убираю `UserManager`, то все работает нормально.

Ошибка:
`InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender' while attempting to activate 'Libr.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'.`

и `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


    services.AddDbContext<BooksContext>(options =>
       options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDbContext<CartContext>(options =>
     options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDbContext<OrdersContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    //services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();



    services.AddScoped<BookRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<CartRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<OrdersRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddScoped<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();

    //services.AddTransient<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
    //services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте прочитать и понять текст вашей ошибки. Если не поможет, наберите ее в гугле (первая же ссылке ведет на ответ). Если снова не поможет, добавьте деталей в вопрос, как вы сами пробовали решить проблему и что у вас не вышло.

Comment: Хороший совет! Но один не дочет.  я пытался гуглить. не понимаю что ему не нравится

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка заключается в том, что `UserManager` зависит от `IEmailSender`, а вы не объявили его в вашем DI контейнере. Добавьте:

```
services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
```